# How to type hint a trait when using the trait to realize multi-inheritance?

Tags: php, oop, traits, type-hinting

Multi-inheritance is realized by using trait, but the type of parameters cannot be limited. For example, the following example

```
trait T{
    function t(){
        echo 'trait';
    }
    // Omit many other codes
}

class B{ } // Assume that B is a third-party module

class C extends B{ // Assume that C must inherit the module B
    use T;
}

// Some functions in some classes in the following client code may need to use several methods in T, like the following.
function f(T $t){ // Type-hinting for the trait T, but there is a problem
    $t->t();
}

f(new C);
```

[Sandbox test found an error](https://onlinephp.io/?s=XVDNSgJRFN4PzDuchaAtwgcwCvQVfAGxEYVQyZECETQzFSVbpKlpqWVJ0mgFOTrqvMz9mVn1Cp1xMqOzuXDO93e_vYN4OC4KoiAfByIy-FOiADihZDQoR2JRkF07PytrpGA4Bs411Omx12n7cbt5O8trA5r_JFqdror0sUW0B97NikLa0g8eBRIJ8KYgjVig2YKhrMALrDEmaoaoL0QtsfqMDXu0c7PF-0A6laXo4Zq55fmA6nmzp3HtmZX0v1Tw2nmSCQn8nh9vJBJtQNQyVfqsOOWjsR3NLFTMTp-3ztn9FZnf8jft34YWlqw2odWxkVua7YzxlCVLnV8PaXECfiDqKyKN8oDO3q0AH7WvRQVFyGKBXqhj6E3WnYrCb5shlx8c8qZRjMV7CtE7VsuALhjS6I-MSQ4tUIrML7Ees3lFlRatnmESFKd3Zeu0vMATa5fMG8XsN2w9h7y7j0qbX4dcUekEfDuebw%2C%2C&v=8.1.8) `Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: f(): Argument #1 ($t) must be of type T, C given`

If `f(T $t)` is changed to `f(C $t)` or `f($t)`, it will be fine, but this is not what I want.
It won't work if the trait is changed to an interface, because the function body can't be written in the interface.
It won't work if the trait is changed to a class, because C has already inherited one class and can't inherit another.
What can we do to realize multi-inheritance and restrict types?

---

I have an idea. I wonder if it can be realized. That is to say, write a module specially designed to handle the exception of trait type, and then include the module globally at the beginning of my project. The logic of the module is roughly as follows:

1. Match the keywords T and C in the exception message `must be of type T, C given`;
2. Use the ReflectionClass to get the code block of C;
3. Search for the keyword `use T` in the code block of C. If found, ignore the exception and continue to execute the code, otherwise, throw the exception.

We can use `set_exception_handler('exception _ handler')` to catch exceptions. The question is how to ignore this exception and ensure that the program continues to execute?

Answer (score 0):

Traits are not classes, we just use them to reuse some code in multiple classes.
You may create an interface and use it as the common type in your method.

Comment: ```
interface I {
    public function t();
}
trait T {
    public function t() {
        echo 'trait';
    }
}

class C implements I {use T;} // both T and I, and it's indispensable. 

function f(I $t) {
    $t->t();
}

f(new C);
```
This way of writing is too cumbersome. I'd rather give up the type-hinting for interface I, such as change `f(I $t)` to `f($t)`

Answer (score 0):

PHP doesn’t support multiple inheritance so it uses traits and interfaces to get around that limitation. PHP does not treat a trait as a class (as you have experienced).

I believe you're trying to force PHP to do something it just can't do. Traits are used as "vehicle" or an independent package to augment, expand, and inject some functionality into classes when the code for that functionality doesn't belong in a parent class, or in an interface.

For example, I've created database access traits to give specific classes the ability to read and write data, and once I wrapped Guzzle functionality into a trait so some classes could make API calls.

You can argue whether these are good examples, or whether these specific examples should have been traits at all (and I might agree). But the point is, traits are generally used to add something that shouldn't be in a parent class. In my cases I chose to add them as traits because it seemed like way too much code to add to a parent class when most of the children were not going to be using those methods, and because multiple classes needed access to that functionality.

In your case,

`function f(T $t){ $t->t(); }`

would be,

`function f(C $c){ $c->t(); }`

because C is using T and t() is a method in T.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! but it is not suitable for this case. Because not only C  but also class D, E or F may use T

Comment: and that is exactly why traits are so useful. You can use T in D, E and F. In PHP the value and use of traits lies in the methods and properties they contain, not in the object itself. 

It sounds like you need to rethink your strategy for getting the result you want. You can't get there the way you want to do it.

Comment: In the current version of PHP, I have to give up the type-hinting for traits, using `f($t)` instead of `f(Trait $t)`. What a pity! I hope this case can be solved in the future version.

Comment: You have to rethink your strategy. You can try to fight it but it's just going to make your life miserable. Just give in and learn to use PHP the way it's created. There's really no use in getting frustrated and angry because PHP doesn't do things the same way other languages do. Either learn to do things the PHP way or find another language that fits the way you like to work. There's no sense in trying to force it to do something it can't do. Traits are not classes. Learn to work with it.